# PHP Form - Return to original page after submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a very simple html page that calls a php script to submit data from a form to a database. Once the user has submitted their data it would be great if they could get a message that says they've been added successfully and then redirect them to the page with the form. The code i'm using is as follows:
HTML file

```
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="insertcustomer.php" method="post" >

<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> 
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
<P>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"> Email: <input type="text" name="email"></P> 
Address1: <input type="text"name="address1"> Address2: <input type="text" name="address2"> City:<input type="text" name="city">
<select name="Gender" id="Gender">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value = "1">Female</option>
        <option value = "2">Male</option>
</select> <input value="Add" type="submit"> </form> </body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("centos-db.local","customerinfo","password","customerinfo");

 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`,
`phone`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `gender`) VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]',
'$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[address1]' ,'$_POST[address2]'
,'$_POST[city]' , '$_POST[gender]' )"; if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Customer Added"; mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/mypage.php">` to the bottom of your php file after `?>`. It will redirect to `http://example.com/mypage.php` after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a redirect to your homepage, like:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

[header reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

You should also consider to escape the user input, for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use javaScript: `document.location.href="myFile.php";`
Or you could post your original form to the same page the form is in and handle the message there. That would also facilitate the displaying of error messages, if any.

Answer (score 1):

use [PHP's Header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

you can show the `successfully submit message` on the same page.It will reduce load time of page and increase user experience.

**index.php :**

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("centos-db.local","customerinfo","password","customerinfo");

     {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    $sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`,
    `phone`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `gender`) VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]',
    '$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[address1]' ,'$_POST[address2]'
    ,'$_POST[city]' , '$_POST[gender]' )"; if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "Customer Added"; mysqli_close($con); 
}
    ?>

    <html> 
    <body> 
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >

    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> 
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
    <P>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"> Email: <input type="text" name="email"></P> 
    Address1: <input type="text"name="address1"> Address2: <input type="text" name="address2"> City:<input type="text" name="city">
    <select name="Gender" id="Gender">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value = "1">Female</option>
            <option value = "2">Male</option>
    </select> <input value="Add" type="submit" name="submit"> </form> </body>
    </html>
```

Here, `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` redirect you on the same page from where you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another action.

```
<form action="/" method="post" >
```

Set a post route/check if the post variables are set and if so give the message.

A common problem here is that if you reload the page the post data will be sent again. That is why you normally use Post-Redirect-Get. You could use something like this at the end of yoour php script.

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
exit;
```

**Notice**: If you redirect from another Script the only possibility to display a message is to send a param in the url or to save it to a database and request the latest message on the originial page.

Answer (score 0):

**You can make use of PHP's Header() function**

give this a try. Im afraid Im not able to test it as I dont have Apache installed on my machine.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("centos-db.wireddog.local","customerinfo","password","customerinfo");

 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`,
`phone`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `gender`) VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]',
'$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[address1]' ,'$_POST[address2]'
,'$_POST[city]' , '$_POST[gender]' )"; if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Customer Added"; mysqli_close($con); 
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //Redirect to the same page
    die;
```

p.s I had to remove the php opening and closing tags as SO does not seem to like rendering the tag in editor.